# Repeating different notifications in one service

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

I'm developing an app that gives a notification at 8 am and 8 pm so what i wanna do is give 2 different notification like at 8 am he say hello it's morning  and at 8 pm he say hello it's evening so  how can i do that by 1 service and 1 alarm manager. 
Can someone gives me full example for that .

Comment: Do you have at least your own `Service` and your own `AlarmManager` class?

Comment: I'm phone now can't get codes  just give me small example like service give a toast only not a notification . My problem is how to make service give at 8 am thing and at 8 pm give another thing .

Comment: Pass an intent extra to your service so your service can recognise which notification needs to be generated.

Comment: And what about alarm manager should i use 2 alarms or there are a way to use one alarm???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class NotifTriggerService extends IntentService {

    public static final String NOTIF_TYPE = "notif_type";

    public static final String NOTIF_TYPE_MORNING = "notif_day";
    public static final String NOTIF_TYPE_NIGHT = "notif_night";


    /**
     * Creates an IntentService.  Invoked by your subclass's constructor.
     */
    public NotifTriggerService() {
        super("Trigger");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        String notifType = intent.getStringExtra(NOTIF_TYPE);
    if (notifType.equals(NOTIF_TYPE_MORNING)) {
        //Send morning notification
    } else if( notifType.equals(NOTIF_TYPE_NIGHT)) {
        //Send night notification            
    }

}
```

Now while starting your service just put an extra like this -

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), YourService.class);
intent.putExtra(YourService.NOTIF_TYPE, YourService.NOTIF_TYPE_MORNING);
```